# Git commit status doesn't resolve the repository in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github, git-status

I am working on integrating sonarqube with jenkins ci. I am building a jenkins job for a branch of certain github repositories.But even after the build is successful the set commit status post build action of jenkins cannot fetch the repository name from the job.
I am using choice parameter for different repositories of a github account and in postbuild action of set commit status of github I am manually entering github repository as https://github.com/account-name/$repository,where $repository is the dynamically taken repository name

Comment: What error you get ?

Comment: It is showing success on post-build action but taking repo[] as blank

Comment: [Set GitHub commit status (universal)] SUCCESS on repos [] (sha:a146613) with context:dev test. Jenkins console displaying this for post-build action set commit status on github